# SQL: Sum timestamp intervals of the same day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm setting up a new SQL query to summarize records from a table of employee attendance. These records are downloaded from a fingerprint or RFID sensor and recorded on the same table. I want to get the amount of hours on the workplace.

Everything works fine if the employee comes in and leaves the workplace once at day. The device generates 2 records on the table and that's are not a problem. It's easy identify entrance and exit time.

But I don't realize how to solve if the person comes in, take a break (leaves workplace) and after that he comes in again until the exit time.

Assume that they are always even records (arrival and exit timestamps) on each interval. Also, an employee never checks in one day and leaves on the next day.

I have the following query. Remember: this only gets the minimum timestamp (arrival time) and the max timestamp (leave time).

```sql
SELECT Userid, Name, Date, Entrance, Exit, Hours FROM
            (SELECT Userid AS user,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(TIME, min(Checktime))) AS Entrance,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(TIME, max(Checktime))) AS Exit,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(TIME, max(Checktime)-min(CheckTime))) AS Hours,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATE, CheckTime)) AS Fecha,
            COUNT(*) AS Regs,
            SUM(edited) AS edited FROM attendance
            WHERE CONVERT(DATE, CheckTime) < CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
            GROUP BY Userid, CONVERT(DATE, CheckTime)) AS Hs
            INNER JOIN Userinfo
            ON Userinfo.Userid = Hs.user
            ORDER BY Date DESC, Name ASC;
```

For example, if the table has the following records:

```
id  |  Logid   |  Userid  |       CheckTime       |  edited
1   |      10  |       1  |    2019-06-18 8:00:00 |     0
2   |      11  |       1  |   2019-06-18 12:00:00 |     0
3   |      12  |       1  |   2019-06-18 15:00:00 |     0
4   |      13  |       1  |   2019-06-18 17:00:00 |     0
5   |      14  |       2  |    2019-06-18 8:00:00 |     0
6   |      15  |       2  |   2019-06-18 17:00:00 |     0
```

What I get:

```
Userid  |  Name     |     Date     |  Entrance  |   Exit   |  Hours  |  edited
     1  |  Gandalf  |  2019-06-18  |    8:00:00 | 17:00:00 | 9:00:00 |      0
     2  |    Frodo  |  2019-06-18  |    8:00:00 | 17:00:00 | 9:00:00 |      0
```

What I need:

```
Userid  |  Name     |     Date     |  Entrance  |   Exit   |  Hours  |  edited
     1  |  Gandalf  |  2019-06-18  |    8:00:00 | 17:00:00 | 6:00:00 |      0
     2  |    Frodo  |  2019-06-18  |    8:00:00 | 17:00:00 | 9:00:00 |      0
```

The total time was calculated from (12:00:00 - 8:00:00) + (17:00:00 - 15:00:00).
The columns "Entrance" and "Exit" on this case are not necessary at all.

Have you an idea how I can solve this? Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you assume that an employee can only take one break per day?

Comment: Thanks! I've forget that. Not necessarily (worst case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assume you have pair enter/exit and handle multiple breaks.

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f37a9/2)**

```
with cte as (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Userid], cast ([CheckTime] as Date) 
                               ORDER BY [CheckTime]) as rn
  FROM Table1 t1
)  
SELECT c1.[Userid], 
       cast (c1.[CheckTime] as Date) as the_day,
       SUM (DATEDIFF (hh, c1.[CheckTime], c2.[CheckTime])) as total_hours
FROM cte c1
JOIN cte c2
  ON c1.rn = c2.rn -1
 AND c1.[Userid] = c2.[Userid]
 AND c1.rn % 2 = 1
GROUP BY c1.[Userid],
         cast (c1.[CheckTime] as Date) ;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| Userid |    the_day | total_hours |
|--------|------------|-------------|
|      1 | 2019-06-18 |           6 |
|      2 | 2019-06-18 |           9 |
```

**NOTE:**

General syntax for [DATEDIFF](https://tableplus.io/blog/2018/09/how-to-use-datediff-function-in-sql-server.html):

```
DATEDIFF(datepart, start_date, end_date)
```

Just realize the function DATEDIFF is used to calculate the time interval between two date values and return it as an integer.

So if you have 08:00 and 09:30 using `hh` as datepart you still get 1h. Maybe is better use `mi` and divide by 60

Comment: Hi Juan, thank you very much for your answer! But I have an issue When I try with the example above, I get dirty data.

With data:
```INSERT INTO Table1
    ([id], [Logid], [Userid], [CheckTime], [edited])
VALUES
    (1, 10, 1, '2019-06-18 08:00:00', 0),
    (2, 11, 1, '2019-06-18 12:00:00', 0),
    (3, 12, 1, '2019-06-18 15:00:00', 0),
    (4, 13, 1, '2019-06-18 17:00:00', 0),
    (5, 14, 2, '2019-06-18 08:00:00', 0),
    (6, 15, 2, '2019-06-18 17:00:00', 0)
;```

I get 15 hours for user 1 and 13 hours for user 2.
The correct answer are 6 and 9

Comment: I've just improved my question. Thank you again!

Comment: Check again, I forget join by userid ... `AND c1.[Userid] = c2.[Userid]`

Comment: GREAT!! That's is what I needed. I've added some lines, so I will post it for everyone else. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Perfect! Juan Carlos's solution works great!

I'm posting this because I've edited some of his code to match the original post requirements.

The code is exactly the same. Only I've changed/added a few lines

```sql
with cte as (
  SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Userid], cast ([CheckTime] as Date)
                               ORDER BY [CheckTime]) as rn
  FROM Table1 t1
  WHERE CAST(CheckTime AS DATE) = '2019-06-17'  -- Filter by specific date 
)
SELECT c1.[Userid],
       cast (c1.[CheckTime] as Date) as the_day,
       -- Return time as HH:MM
       CONVERT(VARCHAR, SUM (DATEDIFF (SECOND , c1.[CheckTime], c2.[CheckTime]))/3600) + ':' + right('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(FLOAT, (SUM (DATEDIFF (SECOND , c1.[CheckTime], c2.[CheckTime]))/60) - ((SUM (DATEDIFF (SECOND , c1.[CheckTime], c2.[CheckTime]))/3600)*60))),2) as total_time
FROM cte c1
JOIN cte c2
  ON c1.rn = c2.rn -1
 AND c1.[Userid] = c2.[Userid]
 AND c1.rn % 2 = 1
GROUP BY c1.[Userid],
         cast (c1.[CheckTime] as Date);
```

This query returns:

```
| Userid |    the_day |  total_time |
|--------|------------|-------------|
|      1 | 2019-06-18 |        6:00 |
|      2 | 2019-06-18 |        9:00 |
```